# How do I get a dynamically created ID?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm an absolute beginner in using javascript and ajax and that's why I'm stuck now. I have a while loop in which there are 2 different buttons. Both work, as I imagine, except for one little thing ...

The `product-id` is always passed only for the first element or, if I change it for the last element.
How can I pass the correct product ID to the script?

**This is my PHP file:**

```
<?php while ( $product = $browse->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) :
    $postid = $product[ 'id' ];
    $userid = 1; ?>

 <div id="content_<?php echo $postid ?>">
 <div id="reload_<?php echo $postid ?>" class="row postfarbe browse">

  <form method='post' action="" onsubmit="return add();">
    <input type="hidden" id="userid" value="<?php echo $userid ?>" class="input-box">
    <input type="hidden" id="productid" value="<?php echo $postid ?>" class="input-box">
    <input type="hidden" id="collection" value="1" class="input-box">
    <input type="hidden" id="wish" value="0" class="input-box">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Add to Collection" class="btn my-2 my-sm-0 btn-outline-dark btn-sm">
  </form>

 </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**My Javascript is:**

```
function add()
{
    var userid = document.getElementById("userid").value;
    var productid = document.getElementById("productid").value;
    var collection = document.getElementById("collection").value;
    var wishlist = document.getElementById("wish").value;
    if(userid && productid && collection && wishlist) {
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'post_collection.php',
            data: {
                user_id:userid,
                product_id:productid,
                collection_id:collection,
                wishlist_id:wishlist
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $("#content_"+ productid).load(" #reload_" + productid);
            }
        });
    }  
    return false;
}
</script>
```

I know that the product id in my example is always the same, but how can I pass the correct one to the script if there are 10 or more entries in the loop?

Comment: an id has to be unique. Now you have several elements with id "productid". You can add counter to the id ("productid2") and add that to the function call `onsubmit="return add(2);">`; where '2' would be a counter/index.

Comment: The better way would be to set an eventhandler on `form.submit` and then use the passed in element (the form) to get the child elements and their values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your problem** is that `id` is unique and can only be assigned once to a element, like so:

```
<p id="paragraph"> This is legal </p>
<p id="paragraph"> This is illegal - It is no longer unique </p>

<p class="paragraph"> This is legal </p>
<p class="paragraph"> This is legal </p>
```

You can access the currently clicked class by using `$(this)` like so:

```
$('.paragraph').click(function() {
    $(this).html('See, totally legal.');
});
```

*[See this example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GYMXvy) to see this in use.*

---

**Your solution** needs to add an [`onclick()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method to a `button`. This then gets the [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) form. You can then [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the class and get the [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) from the form data.

Your form was also **submitting** the action. You need to have a `<button>` of type `button` so it does not submit the action. This must also be a class since it will not be unique if you're multiply creating them.

**Here is a working example to just re-add your AJAX request too.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submit-btn').click(function() {
    var elements = {
      'userid': $(this).parent().find('.userid').val(),
      'productid': $(this).parent().find('.productid').val(),
      'collection': $(this).parent().find('.collection').val(),
      'wish': $(this).parent().find('.wish').val()
    };

    console.log("User ID: " + elements.userid);
    console.log("Product ID: " + elements.productid);
    console.log("Collection: " + elements.collection);
    console.log("Wish: " + elements.wish);

    // TODO: Add your AJAX request using these elements
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- This will be generated by PHP -->

<form method='POST'>
  <input hidden class="userid input-box" value="1">
  <input hidden class="productid input-box" value="1">
  <input hidden class="collection input-box" value="1">
  <input hidden class="wish input-box" value="1">
  <button type="button" class="submit-btn btn my-2 my-sm-0 btn-outline-dark btn-sm"> Add to collection </button>
</form>

<!-- This will be generated by PHP -->
<br />

<form method='POST'>
  <input hidden class="userid input-box" value="2">
  <input hidden class="productid input-box" value="2">
  <input hidden class="collection input-box" value="2">
  <input hidden class="wish input-box" value="2">
  <button type="button" class="submit-btn btn my-2 my-sm-0 btn-outline-dark btn-sm"> Add to collection </button>
</form>
```

---

**Your AJAX Data will look like this:**

```
data: {
    user_id: elements.userid,
    product_id: elements.productid,
    collection_id: elements.collection,
    wishlist_id: elements.wish
}
```

---

**Your PHP code could look like this:**

```
<?php foreach($browse->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $product):
    $id = $product['id'];
    $productDd = $product['product_id'];
    $productCategory = $product['category']; // TODO: change to your column nanme
    $productWishList = $product['wish']; ?>

    <div class="content_<?= $id; ?>">
        <div class="reload_<?= $id; ?> row postfarbe browse">
            <form method='POST'>
                <input hidden class="userid input-box" value="<?= $id; ?>">
                <input hidden class="productid input-box" value="<?= $productCategory; ?>">
                <input hidden class="collection input-box" value="<?= $productCollection; ?>">
                <input hidden class="wish input-box" value="<?= $productWishList; ?>">
                <button type="button" class="submit-btn btn my-2 my-sm-0 btn-outline-dark btn-sm"> Add to collection </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Many Thanks! I think I still have much to learn. The whole example helps me to understand it better now. I tried to give unique IDs, but then the last entry in the loop was always used.

Comment: No worries. Easiest way to remember is, if there is multiple elements: use classes. If there is only a single element: use id's. I'll add what PHP code you need to have on the bottom of this question in figures 5.

Comment: I updated the answer to provide your PHP code. @StefanKlein

Comment: Oh, that was not necessary. I was able to integrate your suggestions well. Thank you very much @Jaquarh, everything works fine now.

Comment: Brilliant. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

I read your code , You want to have multiple entries and want to read / fetch dynamically generated Form's Feilds in the common JS Function Add which is currently referring to FIRST FOUND ELEMENT IN RENDERED HTML - Thats the reason you are getting the same value each time.

You need to alter the logic with little tric - Pass something uniqueness in argument of ADD function

```
<form method='post' action="" onsubmit="return add(<?php echo $postid; ?> );">
<input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $postid; ?>_userid" value="<?php echo $userid ?>" class="input-box">
<input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $postid; ?>_productid" value="<?php echo $postid ?>" class="input-box">
<input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $postid; ?>_collection" value="1" class="input-box">
<input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $postid; ?>_wish" value="0" class="input-box">
<input type="submit" id="<?php echo $postid; ?>_submit" value="Add to Collection" class="btn my-2 my-sm-0 btn-outline-dark btn-sm">
```

NOW read uniquely in ADD Function

```
function add(post_id){

var userid = document.getElementById(post_id+"_userid").value;
var productid = document.getElementById(post_id+"_productid").value;
var collection = document.getElementById(post_id+"_collection").value;
var wishlist = document.getElementById(post_id+"_wish").value;
### Your code as it is ...  
}
```

Hope this make you sense How i have generated in Loop Unique ELEMENT ID and pass same ID in the function as Argument to fetch them in JS.

Comment: This is similiar to what i tried first and i failed badly. The problem is already solved, thanks to @Jaquarh. But thanks for your efforts!